# nginx × socket.ioの環境でヘッダーが追加できない

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

### 現象

クロスドメインの対応で、Access-Control-Allow-Originを書き換えるといいとの記述を見たので、
以下のように記述してみましたが、変化はありません。

```
    var http = require('http'),
  //サーバインスタンス作成
  server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
      res.end('server connected');
  }),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
  server.listen(9090);//9090番ポートで起動
  ・・・
```

### その他補足

- 現在はAccess-Control-Allow-Originにsocket.io.jsを読み込んでいるサイトのホスト名がセットされています。
- nginxのリバースプロキシを使用しています
- nginxの方でもAccess-Control-Allow-Originを書き換える指定を入れましたが、書き換えではなく追記となりました。
- クロスドメインのエラー

  ```
  XML HttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.xx.xx/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=123456789&sid=USkrjwl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://hostsite.aa.bb/' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
  ```

  ※パラメーター値、URLはでたらめです。手打ちしたので綴りミスがあるかもしれないです・・・。

問題の個所がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。

Comment: とりあえず本題とは関係ないことがわかったので一旦回答を取り下げました。

Comment: 了解です、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
Nodeサーバーからheaderを追加変更できなかったので、nginxの設定を書き換えました。
今まで、下記のような書き方をしておりました。

`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`
`proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *`

ですが、下記の書き方で「Access-Control-Allow-Origin」が指定できました。
リバースプロキシ使っているからですかね？

`proxy_set_header Origin *`

ただ、アスタリスク（*）を使った指定だと、また別のエラーが発生したので、今のところホスト名を指定しています。

Comment: というより、socket.io は[リクエストの Origin ヘッダや Referrer ヘッダを見て Access-Control-Allow-Origin を設定している](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/1.3.7/lib/index.js#L62)みたいですね。とすると上手く動かない環境ではこのあたりのヘッダが正しく設定されていなかったんですかね・・・。